# CoovaChilli error: Failed to create redir listen

Tags: linux, centos6.4, coovachilli

I installed Coovachilli version1.30 on Centos 6.4 compiled from source.

Followed all the documentation from all sources I layed my hands on [like this tutorial](http://myconfigure.blogspot.com/2013/04/easyhotspot-in-centos-64-coovachilli-130.html)

But my Coovachilli won't start.

I started Coovachilli on debug mode using  `chilli --fg --debug`,
the output bellow

```
main-opt.c: 605: 0 (Debug) DHCP Listen: 172.16.100.1
main-opt.c: 606: 0 (Debug) UAM Listen: 172.16.100.1
garden.c: 414: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed IP address #0:128: proto=0 host=172.16.100.1 port=80
garden.c: 443: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed www.coova.org
garden.c: 414: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed IP address #1:128: proto=0 host=174.129.195.118 port=0
garden.c: 443: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed 172.16.100.1
garden.c: 414: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed IP address #2:128: proto=0 host=172.16.100.1 port=0
garden.c: 443: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed www.coova.org
garden.c: 387: 0 (Debug) Uamallowed already exists #1:128: proto=0 host=174.129.195.118 port=0
options.c: 443: 0 (Debug) PID 23660 saving options to /usr/local/var/run/chilli.23659.cfg.bin
options.c: 652: 0 (Debug) PID 23659 reloaded binary options file
chilli.c: 7143: 0 (Debug) clock realtime sec 1406208152 nsec 415141634
chilli.c: 7148: 0 (Debug) clock monotonic sec 20567 nsec 895267910
tun.c: 605: 0 (Debug) TX queue length set to 100
tun.c: 1108: 0 (Debug) Running /usr/local/etc/chilli/up.sh
ippool.c: 338: 0 (Debug) Hashlog 16 39933 65536
net.c: 1239: 0 (Debug) Net SNDBUF 229376
net.c: 1242: 0 (Debug) Net RCVBUF 229376
net.c: 1295: 0 (Debug) device eth0 ifindex 2
net.c: 1311: 0 (Debug) lo  address family: 17 (AF_PACKET)
net.c: 1311: 0 (Debug) eth0  address family: 17 (AF_PACKET)
net.c: 1311: 0 (Debug) eth1  address family: 17 (AF_PACKET)
net.c: 1311: 0 (Debug) lo  address family: 2 (AF_INET)
net.c: 1311: 0 (Debug) eth1  address family: 2 (AF_INET)
net.c: 1311: 0 (Debug) tun0  address family: 2 (AF_INET)
dhcp.c: 481: 0 (Debug) hash table size 64 (56)
dhcp.c: 333: 0 (Debug) GARP: Replying to broadcast
dhcp.c: 1173: 0 (Debug) dhcpif (eth0) IPv6 address ::
radius.c: 1315: 0 (Debug) RADIUS client 0.0.0.0:3799
redir.c: 1708: 92 (Protocol not available) setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT)
chilli.c: 7251: 0 (Debug) Failed to create redir listen
```

Comment: Seems like a CoovaChilli can not create a socket connection...can you check to see if there is a process al

Comment: no process is currently using the coova port. i did a netsat -plunt